# ubuntu 22.04 not booting after full disk

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, boot-repair

I'm using linux for some time now. I have dual boot on my machine and everything worked fine.

One day on ubuntu i got warning that disk is too full only 700 mB space left. I put computer to sleep over night not powering it off. In the morning the warning was> disk is too full 0 mB space left. I tried to power off and on computer. But did not got past the ubuntu booting screen.

So I plugged live usb stick with live ubuntu 22.04 tried boot-repair which identified full disk saying I had to delet some files to make space. So I deleted 1 GB of files. But still with no success to boot the original ubuntu.

Can anyone suggest next steps to troubleshoot.

There is report from boot-repair. The ubuntu is installed in sda7
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RmwSp82wfp/

EDIT1:
Before booting screen there is:

```
/dev/sda7: clean, 818525/3892320 files, 14840542/15605760 blocks
5.269296 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol 
\_SB.PCIO.GFXO.D002._BCL AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
5.269309 ACPI Error: Abortingmethod \_SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/sparse-529)
```

EDIT2:
IF I press F2 at the booting screen there is GNOME Display Manager that is failing to start

Comment: You need to free up some hard disk space and then expand the partition Ubuntu is on. What is the size of the partition you install in?

Comment: I will give it a try. Right now Ubuntu is installed on 60 GB. I did expanded once from 40 GB to 60GB. But that was with Ubuntu 18

Comment: I assume you mean Ubuntu 18.04 not Ubuntu Core 18. It is the same procedure assuming you have another partition you can shrink. I will remind you use Windows tools to work with a Windows part ion and Ubuntu tools to work with a Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Yes of course Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Addition of some space to existing ubuntu partition helped. I shrinked windows volume by another 40 GB and added to ubuntu partition. And after that it booted again normaly.